# Market Research Tabulation Reports in R

Tags: r, data-analysis, spss

Does anyone know of a R package that does the same thing as SPSS's Custom Tables? Please note: this is not a crosstab wherein two questions are tabled against one another. Please see Wincross as an example of a software that does this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. The package is called expss. 
Link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/expss/vignettes/tables-with-labels.html

Comment: It's helpful to post a package that answers the question. But it's even more helpful to  explain how it does the same thing as SPSS's Customs Tables instead of expecting people to read a long webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas to manipulate tables.

http://personal.colby.edu/personal/m/mgimond/RIntro/04_Manipulating_data_tables.html